# How to open the Phone, email, another url from the WKWebView in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am new with the WKWebview in Objective-c. I have loaded the website in the wkwebview as follow,

```
 WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
 WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
 webView.navigationDelegate = self;
 [webView loadRequest:BookingUrl];
 self.view = webView;
```

In the website, there are phone numbers, mail, other links, How to open the same while clicking those inside the web view,

for example, if clicked the mail button from the web view, it needs to open the mail on the phone.

Any help will be really appreciated.